# How to count the number of occurances of a character within a data set in R

Tags: r, character

I am currently playing around with a mock data set in which I record the number of times that a given species of flower is visited by a type of bee. Part of my data set might look something like this:

```
Plant   Visitor.1   Visitor.2   Visitor.3
  1     Bombus      Bombus      NA
  2     Apis        Bombus      Apis
  3     NA          NA          NA
  4     Apis        NA          NA
  5     NA          NA          NA
  6     Apis        NA          NA
  7     Apis        Apis        Halictid
  8     Apis        Apis        NA
  9     Bombus      Halictid    Halictid
 10     NA          NA          NA
 11     NA          NA          NA
 12     NA          NA          NA
 13     Halictid    NA          NA
```

Is there a way for me to count how many times that "Bombus", "Apis", "Halictid", etc. occurs in each column, or even across all three columns at once? I have read a lot on how to do this with strings of data, but not with a data set such as this. I'm not too sure where to start, to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
library(qdapTools)
addmargins(t(mtabulate(df1[-1])),2)
#          Visitor.1 Visitor.2 Visitor.3 Sum
#Apis             5         2         1   8
#Bombus           2         2         0   4
#Halictid         1         1         2   4
```

If you need the count only for the whole dataset

```
table(unlist(df1[-1]))

#   Apis   Bombus Halictid 
#    8        4        4
```

I am not sure if you need this for each row i.e for each 'Plant'.  In that case,

```
Un1 <- unique(na.omit(unlist(df1[-1])))
res <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN=function(x) table(factor(x, levels=Un1))))
cbind(res, Sum=rowSums(res))
#     Bombus Apis Halictid Sum
#[1,]      2    0        0   2
#[2,]      1    2        0   3
#[3,]      0    0        0   0
#[4,]      0    1        0   1
#[5,]      0    0        0   0
#[6,]      0    1        0   1
#[7,]      0    2        1   3
#[8,]      0    2        0   2
#[9,]      1    0        2   3
#[10,]     0    0        0   0
#[11,]     0    0        0   0
#[12,]     0    0        0   0
#[13,]     0    0        1   1
```

Or using `mtabulate`

```
 addmargins(as.matrix(mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])))),2)
```

#### Update

If you need for `columns` (using only base R),

```
addmargins(t(apply(df1[-1], 2, FUN=function(x) table(factor(x, levels=Un1)))))
#           Bombus Apis Halictid Sum
#Visitor.1      2    5        1   8
#Visitor.2      2    2        1   5
#Visitor.3      0    1        2   3
#Sum            4    8        4  16
```

Or a more compact version would be

```
 addmargins(table(stack(df1[-1])[2:1]))
 #           values
 #ind         Apis Bombus Halictid Sum
 # Visitor.1    5      2        1   8
 # Visitor.2    2      2        1   5
 # Visitor.3    1      0        2   3
 # Sum          8      4        4  16
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Plant = 1:13, Visitor.1 = c("Bombus", "Apis", 
NA, "Apis", NA, "Apis", "Apis", "Apis", "Bombus", NA, NA, NA, 
"Halictid"), Visitor.2 = c("Bombus", "Bombus", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Apis", "Apis", "Halictid", NA, NA, NA, NA), Visitor.3 = c(NA, 
"Apis", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Halictid", NA, "Halictid", NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("Plant", "Visitor.1", "Visitor.2", "Visitor.3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple solution, try copy and pasting the code below into your R console:

```
##  Create an artificial data set.  
example.data = 
     data.frame(col1 = c("Bob", "Jane", "Mary"), col2 = c("Mary", "Joe", "Sam"))

##  Count how many times 'x' appears in each column of the data set.
##  Lets count how many times 'Bob' appears in each column.
apply(example.data, 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Bob')))
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful, Chris -- akrun, I am going to get qdaptools and ply tomorrow morning, I think. They both seem to be helpful.

Comment: The only thing is that I would like to keep the code as close to the basic packages that R provides as possible-- I want to leave the finished product with the lab once I leave and don't want to have to remind everybody to download different packages to run the program. Do you think that I could just insert code for functions into the program as I need them, or is that not a good idea?

Comment: I generally like to minimize the use of external packages.